# WCF Restful service and WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, wcf-rest

WCF Restful service and WCF Data Service both are same? or else any difference is there?

Comment: You might find this useful http://forums.asp.net/t/1772225.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Both are not **same**, even though both support RestFul features.

[WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is their full OData service stack, it both enables and defines OData.
OData uses the entity-relationship conventions of the Entity Data Model to expose resources as sets of entities that are related by associations. Any client that supports OData can only access it.

WCF Restful service (*WCF WebAPI*) was  Microsoft's effort to bring REST ful support to WCF and is [replaced](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Web%20API%20is%20now%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API) by [ASP.Net web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

There is no longer development happening in WCF Restful services, but Microsoft is still supporting WCF Data Services.